# Trivial Assertions about Sets not Verifying in Dafny

Tags: dafny

Tutorial [Collections](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Collections) contains the following code

```
method m()
{
   assert (set x | x in {0,1,2,3,4,5} && x < 3) == {0,1,2};
}
```

which, however, currently does not verify in the Dafny system available at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/):

```
stdin.dfy(3,11): Warning: /!\ No terms found to trigger on.
stdin.dfy(3,48): Error: assertion violation
Dafny program verifier finished with 0 verified, 1 error
```

This simpler example

```
method m() { assert (set x : nat | x in {0}) == {0}; }
```

doesn't verify either:

```
stdin.dfy(1,21): Warning: /!\ No terms found to trigger on.
stdin.dfy(1,45): Error: assertion violation
Dafny program verifier finished with 0 verified, 1 error
```

I think both examples should verify; am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both true. There was a missing condition in Dafny's encoding that made these not verify. I fixed it. Thanks for the bug report.

Rustan

Comment: Dear Rustan, thanks for the answer. I made the tests again at rise4fun and the bug is still there, but I understand that it may take some time until the Dafny system running there is updated.

Comment: I checked in the fix to the sources. It will go out to rise4fun when we next put a new version there.